# How to create some sort of template for sections in an SNMP - MIB file

Tags: snmp, mib

We have a software suite that gathers health information from it's modules (services).
We deal internally with this health info, but we also want to use SNMP to let the outside world know what the status of the modules is.
Instead of using a MIB file and having to implement SNMP in every module, we want to use SNMP in one centralized service, with one MIB file.
This has its advantages, but the accompanying MIB file is getting huge because of the fact that every module may contain a complete copy of its peer modules.
This looks like this, and this just a very simple example.

[image: example mib tree]

The question is:
Is there a way to construct sub sections in a mib-tree in order to make the MIB-file more maintainable?
It would be so nice to create a sort of template for a module with all its child objects and just create objects from this template.

Is this possible somehow?

Below is the MIB-file for this example mib tree:

```
    MYCOMP-MYAPP-MIB DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

   IMPORTS
        MODULE-IDENTITY, OBJECT-TYPE, NOTIFICATION-TYPE, enterprises
           FROM SNMPv2-SMI
        TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
           FROM SNMPv2-TC;

mycomp             OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {enterprises 12345}

myapp MODULE-IDENTITY                      
       LAST-UPDATED  "201810220000Z"
       ORGANIZATION  "MyCompany"
       CONTACT-INFO  ""
       DESCRIPTION   ""
       ::= { mycomp 40 }

systemInfoGroup OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::= {myapp 2}

ErrorStatus ::= TEXTUAL-CONVENTION
    STATUS     current   
    DESCRIPTION
        "Status"
    SYNTAX     INTEGER {
        normal(0),
        error(1),
    }

sysManagerGroup OBJECT IDENTIFIER 
::= {systemInfoGroup 1}

sysManagerModule1 OBJECT IDENTIFIER 
::= {sysManagerGroup 1}

sysManagerModule1Version  OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX  OCTET STRING (SIZE (1..100))
   ACCESS  read-only
   STATUS  current
   DESCRIPTION
           "Contains the version string of the software module."
   ::= { sysManagerModule1 1 }

sysManagerModule1Uptime  OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX  OCTET STRING (SIZE (1..100))
   ACCESS  read-only
   STATUS  current
   DESCRIPTION
           "Up time."
   ::= { sysManagerModule1 2 }

sysManagerModule1ErrorA OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  ErrorStatus                
    ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    ::= { sysManagerModule1 4 }

sysManagerModule1ErrorB OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX   ErrorStatus 
    ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    ::= { sysManagerModule1 5 }

sysManagerModule1ErrorC OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  ErrorStatus 
    ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    ::= { sysManagerModule1 6 }

sysManagerModule2 OBJECT IDENTIFIER 
::= {sysManagerGroup 2}

sysManagerModule2Version  OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX  OCTET STRING (SIZE (1..100))
   ACCESS  read-only
   STATUS  current
   DESCRIPTION
           "Contains the version string of the software module."
   ::= { sysManagerModule2 1 }

sysManagerModule2Uptime  OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX  OCTET STRING (SIZE (1..100))
   ACCESS  read-only
   STATUS  current
   DESCRIPTION
           "Up time."
   ::= { sysManagerModule2 2 }

sysManagerModule2ErrorA OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  ErrorStatus                
    ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    ::= { sysManagerModule2 4 }

sysManagerModule2ErrorB OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX   ErrorStatus 
    ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    ::= { sysManagerModule2 5 }

sysManagerModule2ErrorC OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX  ErrorStatus 
    ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS  current
    ::= { sysManagerModule2 6 }
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully grok your use case (I'm not completely getting the "every module may contain a complete copy of its peer modules" part, particularly since your modules themselves actually "have" *nothing* if you're centralising the information in one place), but this seems like a perfect opportunity for *tables*. This is analogous to an array of structs, in C-like languages.

Instead of having Version, Uptime, ErrorA, ErrorB and ErrorC repeated (both in the MIB and in the actual logical tree) a million times, you have a *table* that contains five columns, and populate it with as many rows as you need. The syntax/form of each column need only be specified once.

You'd have an additional column (put it first) for the "index" of each row, i.e. module number.

My SMI is rusty, but the definitions would look something like this:

```
sysManagerGroup OBJECT IDENTIFIER 
::= { systemInfoGroup 1 }

sysManagerModuleTable OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF SysManagerModuleEntry
   MAX-ACCESS   not-accessible
   STATUS       current
   DESCRIPTION  "Table of modules being monitored"
::= { sysManagerGroup 1 }

sysManagerModuleEntry OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX       SysManagerModuleEntry
   MAX-ACCESS   not-accessible
   STATUS       current
   DESCRIPTION  "A row in the table of modules being monitored"
   INDEX        { sysManagerModuleId }
::= { sysManagerModuleTable 1 }

SysManagerModuleEntry ::= { SEQUENCE
   sysManagerModuleId       Integer32,
   sysManagerModuleVersion  OCTET STRING,
   sysManagerModuleUptime   OCTET STRING,
   sysManagerModuleErrorA   ErrorStatus,
   sysManagerModuleErrorB   ErrorStatus,
   sysManagerModuleErrorC   ErrorStatus,
}

sysManagerModuleId OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX     Integer32,
   MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
   STATUS     current
   DESCRIPTION "Numeric ID of the module"
   ::= { sysManagerModuleEntry 1 }

sysManagerModuleVersion  OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX     OCTET STRING (SIZE (1..100))
   MAX-ACCESS read-only
   STATUS     current
   DESCRIPTION
           "Contains the version string of the software module."
   ::= { sysManagerModuleEntry 2 }

sysManagerModuleUptime  OBJECT-TYPE
   SYNTAX     OCTET STRING (SIZE (1..100))
   MAX-ACCESS read-only
   STATUS     current
   DESCRIPTION
           "Up time."
   ::= { sysManagerModuleEntry 3 }

sysManagerModuleErrorA OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX     ErrorStatus                
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS     current
    ::= { sysManagerModuleEntry 4 }

sysManagerModuleErrorB OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX     ErrorStatus 
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS     current
    ::= { sysManagerModuleEntry 5 }

sysManagerModuleErrorC OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX     ErrorStatus 
    MAX-ACCESS read-only
    STATUS     current
    ::= { sysManagerModuleEntry 6 }
```

And that's it — no repeated definitions required. At runtime, add as many rows as you need/want.

Individual entries will be directly accessible as follows:

```
4.1.12345.40.2.1.1.1.<ID>.<FIELD>
```

e.g. module 2's ErrorB is

```
4.1.12345.40.2.1.1.1.2.5
```

and module 48,570's Uptime is

```
4.1.12345.40.2.1.1.1.48570.3
```

Of course, your remote Manager won't know the number of rows ahead of time, but that's fine: Managers will use a "walk" or variant — some combination of *GetNext* or *GetBulk* requests — to discover the contents of the table.

Plug these SMIv2 definitions into your MIB and feed the MIB to your SNMP Manager, and you should see how it improves the layout. How to actually populate the table will depend on your Agent software.

Note that the "table" and "entry" objects are actually kind of pseudo-objects, and thus must have `not-accessible` access level; the entry's index is a real value but should be `not-accessible` because its value is logically part of the OID for each entry, rather than a distinct object that you can poll.

By the way, enterprise number 12345 has been [assigned](https://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers) to *VWB Group*; unless you're them, you will need to [get your own](https://pen.iana.org/pen/PenApplication.page).

Comment: No problem, I just used 12345 as an example.

Thanks for the answer, I can work from this!